# Ubuntu 20.04 boot hangs after update

Tags: boot, 20.04, startup

After running an update in Ubuntu 20.04, my boot performance is seriously degraded. Running `dmesg` highlights a few problematic processes.

```
...
[   21.921354] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   22.157236] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[   27.297351] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   42.913317] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   43.021293] usb usb1-port4: attempt power cycle
[   43.673232] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[   48.929356] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[   54.305334] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[   54.541242] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[   59.681384] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[   65.057363] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[   65.165292] usb usb1-port4: unable to enumerate USB device
...
[   66.871831] NET: Registered protocol family 38
[  128.664088] usb 1-14: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
...
```

After running `systemd-analyze`, you can see the boot time is... total crap.

```
Startup finished in 29.969s (firmware) + 10.657s (loader) + 1.854s (kernel) + 1min 4.220s (userspace) = 1min 46.701s 
graphical.target reached after 30.301s in userspace
```

Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I assume you did not have these usb errors before upgrade, you could check the older logs to confirm

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my connected GoPro was drawing too much power from USB and causing the boot to fail. Solved.